# Weird pickling error running Apache Beam Python on Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We're running a fairly simple job which reads JSON, does some processing and outputs JSON.
For some reason, this always fails with a very weird "pickling" error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'generator'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.generator failed [while running 'map to user_activity']
```

It fails almost immediately on processing the first line of data.  The preceding stage emits a tuple of (String, []).  When the 'map to user_activity' stage runs, it will fail if it tries to iterate the [].

There are no lambdas, which seem to be a common source of these pickling errors.  We've narrowed it down to iterating over the [] in the input tuple.  If we don't iterate, then the job will "work".  As soon as we do:

```
for entry in input_tuple:
    pass
```

The job fails immediately.

**** Update ****
It turns out, iterating over the input tuple isn't the key.  ANY for loop in the Map function will cause a crash, even something like this:

```
q=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for a in q:
  pass
```

Here's the full stack trace for the error:

```
An exception was raised when trying to execute the workitem 4985068250752295797 : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 582, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 166, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 38, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/native_operations.c:3175)
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 39, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/native_operations.c:3079)
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 44, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/native_operations.c:2994)
    with self.spec.source.reader() as reader:
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 54, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/native_operations.c:2938)
    self.output(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 154, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:5783)
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 86, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:3622)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 339, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:11089)
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 340, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:11043)
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 382, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive (apache_beam/runners/common.c:10156)
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 390, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:10458)
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 415, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented (apache_beam/runners/common.c:11363)
    raise
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 388, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:10371)
    self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 189, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:6270)
    self.output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 480, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs (apache_beam/runners/common.c:12500)
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 86, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:3622)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 339, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:11089)
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 340, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:11043)
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 382, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive (apache_beam/runners/common.c:10156)
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 390, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:10458)
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 431, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented (apache_beam/runners/common.c:11673)
    raise new_exn, None, original_traceback
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 388, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:10371)
    self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 189, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:6270)
    self.output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 480, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs (apache_beam/runners/common.c:12500)
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 84, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:3588)
    self.update_counters_start(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 90, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.update_counters_start (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:3808)
    self.opcounter.update_from(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 62, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.update_from (apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.c:2396)
    self.do_sample(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 80, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.do_sample (apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.c:3017)
    self.coder_impl.get_estimated_size_and_observables(windowed_value))
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 730, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables (apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.c:22968)
    def get_estimated_size_and_observables(self, value, nested=False):
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 739, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables (apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.c:22687)
    self._value_coder.get_estimated_size_and_observables(
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 260, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.FastPrimitivesCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables (apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.c:9578)
    self.encode_to_stream(value, out, nested)
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 298, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.FastPrimitivesCoderImpl.encode_to_stream (apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.c:10416)
    self.fallback_coder_impl.encode_to_stream(value, stream, nested)
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 154, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CallbackCoderImpl.encode_to_stream (apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.c:5883)
    return stream.write(self._encoder(value), nested)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 437, in <lambda>
    lambda x: dumps(x, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL), pickle.loads)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'generator'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.generator failed [while running 'map to user_activity']
```

Comment: It turns out, iterating over the input tuple isn't the key.  ANY for loop in the Map function will cause a crash, even something like this:
`q=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
`for a in q:`
`pass`

Comment: What version of Beam are you using? Can you include a more complete snippet of your code?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is due to using beam.Map rather than beam.FlatMap for a function where you wish for multiple elements to be returned (yielded?)

Comment: Just accidentally used `beam.Map` instead of the `beam.FlatMap` and your answer just brought my eyes to the root of the problem. I think it should be an accepted answer and it’s worse clarifying that it is actual for any transform using `yield` for multiple outputs.

Comment: I can confirm this, I had a similar problem: I had a `Map(my_func)` step, where `my_func` read in the input dict element, but instead of altering the object and yielding it, I had to create a new dict and yield that dict. It failed with an error like the OP's.  I then changed it to `ParDo(MyClass())`, where the `process` part of `MyClass` was **exactly** identical to the `my_func`.  It worked fine, no pickling errors.